# White noise from headphones in Ubuntu 18.04.1 on Dell XPS 13 9370

Tags: sound, dell, headphones, xps, noise

Whenever I plug in my headphones on my Dell XPS 9370 I hear a white hissing sound. Apparently, this was common in the XPS 9360 as well and can be fixed by setting the headphone mic volume to 10dB.

`$ amixer -c PCH cset 'name=Headphone Mic Boost Volume' 1`

This doesn't work on the 9370.

The sound card is a realtek ALC3271. I noticed that Realtek provide a file for Linux called patch_realtek.c. In the Linux linux-4.15.18 kernel (closest version I could see to my kernel) there is [no mention of ALC3271](http://tomoyo.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c?v=linux-4.15.18).

However, it appears at some point and is present in the [latest patch](http://tomoyo.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c). I'm thinking that I might need to add this patch to my kernel as i am running the `4.15.0-39-generic` kernel. Does this seem like a reasonable thing to try?

How would I go about applying the patch above?

Thanks

[EDIT] ALC3271 does appear in the 4.15 kernel so the question is more or less incorrect.

Comment: Seems this is bug that is at least 2 years old that was never fixed or recently reappeared due to a regression, see the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1654448. The workaround with the amixer command works for me on my XPS 9360.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that qualifies for a full answer but:
There's a doc describing the process step by step on example:
https://www.proware.com.tw/support/software/cdb16patch-lnx/linux-patch.pdf

in fact, you apply the patch with a `patch` tool, same as any `patchfile` is applied. Anyways, not having 9370 here, so wish you luck in the process. I'd wait for official kernel release, though.

Comment: Thanks for the link. How would I go about checking the version of patch_realtek.c that is in my kernel `4.15.0-39-generic`?

Comment: first update to latest 4.15.X kernel, then try http://tomoyo.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c?v=linux-4.15.18

Comment: It appears I've been mistaken anyway. ALC3271 is listed in 4.15 :(. I'll need to find a different way to get rid of the white noise.

Comment: So I updated to `4.19.3-041903-generic` using [this guide](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/) but the white noise remains...

Comment: well, then the chances are few: you didn't apply the patch to the kernel correctly, or your system is not running the patched kernel or that kernel patch wasn't meant to fix YOUR issue (there may be multiple causes of it and patch could only fix one of them). Sorry I can't help more, but without 9370 on hand, it's really hard to debug anything on my end.